# Horizontal alignments getting messed when trying to add bootstrap cards horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My horizontal alignments gets messed when when I try to stack 2 bootstrap cards in a row. The problem is I get the horizontal scroller enabled the very moment I try to add these cards.
Can anyone suggest me a solution please

Code adapted from bootstrap documentation is as below

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your problem, and if possible modify the question so that it will be clear to understand the problem

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti thanks for your kind response.It has been included now

Comment: I tried your code in the codepen: https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/gOMQzox?editors=1010 , it looks fine to me, can you post the whole code, as in the current one I cannot see the header "Check out our latest deals below".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess would be, from Bootstrap's official docs,

> Cards assume no specific width to start, so they’ll be 100% wide
> unless otherwise stated.

To fix the horizontal scrolling issue you can add a container class to your row

```
<div class="row row-container">   <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>   </div>   <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>   </div> </div>
```

and add the following styles

```
.row-container{
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Or give your row an auto margin left and right

```
.row-container{
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

You can see the pen here. https://codepen.io/fuzzysid/pen/vYKQjWy